# How to use a shell command to only show the first column and last column in a text file?

Tags: shell, sed, awk

I need some help to figure out how to use the sed command to only show the first column and last column in a text file. Here is what I have so far for column 1:

```
cat logfile | sed 's/\|/ /'|awk '{print $1}'
```

My feeble attempt at getting the last column to show as well was:

```
cat logfile | sed 's/\|/ /'|awk '{print $1}{print $8}'
```

However this takes the first column and last column and merges them together in one list.
Is there a way to print the first column and last columns clearly with sed and awk commands?

Sample input:

```
foo|dog|cat|mouse|lion|ox|tiger|bar
```

Comment: Please provide some sample input.

Answer (score 145):

Almost there. Just put both column references next to each other.

```
cat logfile | sed 's/|/ /' | awk '{print $1, $8}'
```

Also note that you don't need `cat` here.

```
sed 's/|/ /' logfile | awk '{print $1, $8}'
```

Also note you can tell `awk` that the column separators is `|`, instead of blanks, so you don't need `sed` either.

```
awk -F '|' '{print $1, $8}' logfile
```

---

As per [suggestions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/136884/how-to-use-the-sed-command-to-only-show-the-first-column-and-last-column-in-a-te/136886?noredirect=1#comment218445_136886) by [Caleb](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/1925/caleb), if you want a solution that still outputs the last field, even if there are not exactly eight, you can use `$NF`.

```
awk -F '|' '{print $1, $NF}' logfile
```

Also, if you want the output to retain the `|` separators, instead of using a space, you can specify the output field separators. Unfortunately, it's a bit more clumsy than just using the `-F` flag, but here are three approaches.

- You can assign the input and output field separators in `awk` itself, in the BEGIN block.

  ```
  awk 'BEGIN {FS = OFS = "|"} {print $1, $8}' logfile
  ```
- You can assign these variables when calling `awk` from the command line, via the `-v` flag.

  ```
  awk -v 'FS=|' -v 'OFS=|' '{print $1, $8}' logfile
  ```
- or simply:

  ```
  awk -F '|' '{print $1 "|" $8}' logfile
  ```

Comment: Good job breaking down how this problem can be simplified. You might add a note about how to use `|` as an output separator instead of the default space for string concatenation. Also you could explain to use `$NF` instead of hard coding `$8` to get the last column.

Comment: after that how to update the file?

Comment: @pankajprasad Write to a new file with `>` then overwrite the old one, or use `sponge`. This is really a new question though.

Comment: @Sparhawk it works, but reaming content is erased. how to deal with that?

Comment: @pankajprasad You need to ask a new question. Click the big blue button up the top that says "Ask Question".

Answer (score 31):

You are using `awk` anyway:

```
awk '{ print $1, $NF }' file
```

Comment: Wouldn't you need to specify the input field separator (since in this case it seems to  be `|` rather that space) with `-F\|` or similar? Also what if he wanted to use the same delimiter for output?

Comment: @Caleb Probably: I was waiting for the OP to confirm what *exactly* the input looked like, rather than trying to guess based on the non-working examples...

Comment: Note that that assumes the input contains at least 2 fields.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas OP clearly stated in code that it has eight fields, always.

Comment: @michaelb958 I think "clearly" is overstating the case, just a little :)

Comment: @michaelb958, though I'd agree that will probably address the OP's specific requirements, I think it's still worth mentioning for anyone coming here wanting to retain the first and last field on the input. Leaving it as a comment (as I did) is probably enough.

Answer (score 19):

Just replace from the first to last `|` with a `|` (or space if you prefer):

```
sed 's/|.*|/|/'
```

Note that though there's no `sed` implementation where `|` is special (as long as *extended* regular expressions are not enabled via `-E` or `-r` in some implementations), `\|` itself is special in some like GNU `sed`. So you should *not* escape `|` if you intend it to match the `|` character.

If replacing with space and if the input may already contain lines with only one `|`, then, you'll have to treat that specially as `|.*|` won't match on those. That could be:

```
sed 's/|\(.*|\)\{0,1\}/ /'
```

(that is make the `.*|` part optional) Or:

```
sed 's/|.*|/ /;s/|/ /'
```

or:

```
sed 's/\([^|]*\).*|/\1 /'
```

If you want the first and eighth fields regardless of the number of fields in the input, then it's just:

```
cut -d'|' -f1,8
```

<sup><sup>(all those would work with any POSIX compliant utility assuming the input forms valid text (in particular, the `sed` ones will generally not work if the input has bytes or sequences of bytes that don't form valid characters in the current locale like for instance `printf 'unix|St\351phane|Chazelas\n' | sed 's/|.*|/|/'` in a UTF-8 locale)).</sup></sup>

Answer (score 11):

If you find yourself awk- and sed-less, you can achieve the same thing with coreutils:

```
paste <(           cut -d'|' -f1  file) \ 
      <(rev file | cut -d'|' -f1 | rev)
```

Comment: `cut` is cleaner and more compact than awk/sed when you are just interested in the first column, or if the delimeters are fixed (i.e. not a variable number of spaces).

Comment: Pretty elegant!

Answer (score 3):

It seems like you are try to get the first and last fields of text  which are delimited by `|`.

I assumed your log file contains the text like below,

```
foo|dog|cat|mouse|lion|ox|tiger|bar
bar|dog|cat|mouse|lion|ox|tiger|foo
```

And you want the output like,

```
foo bar
bar foo
```

If yes, then here comes the command for your's

Through GNU sed,

```
sed -r 's~^([^|]*).*\|(.*)$~\1 \2~' file
```

**Example:**

```
$ echo 'foo|dog|cat|mouse|lion|ox|tiger|bar' | sed -r 's~^([^|]*).*\|(.*)$~\1 \2~'
foo bar
```

Comment: The columns are not delimited by a pipe | but they are in columns, I am interested in using sed but not using the awk command like you did in your command:                                                         sed -r 's~^([^|]*).*\|(.*)$~\1 \2~' file

Comment: "The columns are not delimited by a pipe | but they are in columns", you mean columns are separated by spaces?

Comment: A sample input and an output would be better.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably do it with `sed` - I would anyway - but, just cause no one has written this one yet:

```
while IFS=\| read col1 cols
do  printf %10s%-s\\n "$col1 |" " ${cols##*|}"
done <<\INPUT
foo|dog|cat|mouse|lion|ox|tiger|bar
INPUT
```

#### OUTPUT

```
     foo | bar
```